# Cannot find class in classpath: packagename.classname

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, testng

I am using ant and testng

here is my **testng.xml**

```
<suite name="StudioVox Behavioural Tests" verbose="3" parallel="classes" 
    thread-count="4">
    <test name="StudioVoxLifeCycle">
        <classes>
            <class name="studio.Studiovox" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

**Eclipse Details**
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Kepler Service Release 1
Build id: 20130919-0819

**java version "1.7.0-ea"**

I am getting following error while running from cmd

```
run:
   [testng] [TestNG] [ERROR]
   [testng] Cannot find class in classpath: studio.Studiovox
   [testng] The tests failed.
```

**build.xml**

```
<project  name="grok-web-automation" default="run" basedir=".">
    <property name="src" location="src" />
    <property name="build" location="build" />
    <property name = "lib.dir" value="${basedir}/lib" />
    <property name = "testng.output.dir" value="${basedir}/results" />

    <path id="classpath">
      <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**/*.jar" /> 
       <pathelement location="build" />
    </path>

   <!-- create build folder, testng_output folder and remove old log file -->
    <target name="init">
        <delete dir="build" />
        <delete dir="testng_output" />
        <delete file="Test_Auto.log" />
        <mkdir dir="${build}" />
    </target>
    <!-- build all java file to class binary -->
    <target name="compile" depends="init">
        <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}" classpathref="classpath" includeantruntime="false" />
    </target>

    <!-- execute testng after compile, then generate report -->
    <target name="run" depends="compile">
        <mkdir dir="testng.output.dir" />
        <taskdef name="testng" classname="org.testng.TestNGAntTask">
                    <classpath>
                        <pathelement location="./lib/testng-6.8.5.jar" />
                    </classpath>
        </taskdef>

        <!-- config testng -->
        <testng outputdir="testng.output.dir" classpathref="classpath">

            <sysproperty key="url" value="${url}" />
            <sysproperty key="os" value="${os}" />
            <sysproperty key="browser" value="${browser}" />
            <!-- execute testcase -->
            <xmlfileset dir="./SupportBuildXML" includes="testngstudio.xml" />
        </testng>
    </target>
</project>
```